# scipy minimize not always solving function

Tags: python, scipy, finance

Sorry, a little finance related on the topic, but also a scipy/python question. For context of what I am trying to do, it's literally the same as these two blog posts.
https://quantdare.com/risk-parity-in-python/
https://thequantmba.wordpress.com/2016/12/14/risk-parityrisk-budgeting-portfolio-in-python/

So I have a bunch of returns on stocks, and I want to equalize the risk contributions of each stock. To do this I will need to solve for the weights that will give me an equal risk contribution for each using the scipy minimize optimizer.

So I will pass in my target risk contributions, and my initial guess into the optimizer. For example, 6 stocks. My initial guess is merely 1/6 of the total 100% weight in the portfolio.

```
initial_weight = [0.16666666666667, 0.16666666666667, 0.16666666666667,
              0.16666666666667, 0.16666666666667, 0.16666666666667]
risk_contrib_target =[0.16666666666667, 0.16666666666667, 0.16666666666667,
              0.16666666666667, 0.16666666666667, 0.16666666666667]
```

This was taken from the quantmba link, so all credit to that guy. It looks right to me.

```
 # risk budgeting optimization
def calculate_portfolio_var(w,V):
    # function that calculates portfolio risk
    w = np.matrix(w)
    return (w*V*w.T)[0,0]

def calculate_risk_contribution(w,V):
    # function that calculates asset contribution to total risk
    w = np.matrix(w, dtype=object)
    sigma = np.sqrt(calculate_portfolio_var(w,V))
    # Marginal Risk Contribution
    MRC = V*w.T
    # Risk Contribution
    RC = np.multiply(MRC,w.T)/sigma
    RC = RC / sum(RC)
    return RC

def risk_budget_objective(x,pars):
    # calculate portfolio risk
    V = pars[0]# covariance table
    x_t = pars[1] # risk target in percent of portfolio risk
    sig_p =  np.sqrt(calculate_portfolio_var(x,V)) # portfolio sigma
    risk_target = np.asmatrix(x_t, dtype=object)
    asset_RC = calculate_risk_contribution(x,V)
    J = sum(np.square(asset_RC-risk_target.T))[0,0] * 1000 # sum of squared error
    return J
```

I also have a list of dates that I am running through to solve this many times over a time period.

```
rebalance_dates = my_list_of_dates
```

I noticed that sometimes, it doesn't solve this correctly. This is easy to check because the way it is set up, the function should have a 0 solution. Also I can check the risk contribution afterwards to see that they reached my target. To get around this, I kick it to basin hopping if it does not find this 0 solution. I think it is solving a local minimum and not a global minimum and I read this is one solution to that problem.

The get_returns_matrix function is just getting the data that I want from one of my files. This part is not important.

```
returns_matrix = get_returns_matrix(asset_returns, 60, date, components)
```

This is the optimization.

```
for date in rebalance_dates:
    print(date)
    returns_matrix = get_returns_matrix(asset_returns, 60, date, components)
    covariance = np.cov(returns_matrix)
    annual_covar = [map(lambda x:x * 260, group) for group in covariance]
    annual_covar = [list(x) for x in annual_covar]
    cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1.0},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x})
    res= minimize(risk_budget_objective, initial_weight, args=[annual_covar, risk_contrib_target], method='SLSQP',constraints=cons, 
              options={'disp': False, 'ftol': .00000000001, 'eps' : .0000000000000005, 'maxiter':1000})
    if res.fun > .00000000001:
        print("Kick to basin hopping")
        minimizer_kwargs = dict(method="SLSQP", constraints=cons, args=[annual_covar, risk_contrib_target], options={'ftol': .000000000000000000001, 'eps' : .0000000000000005, 'maxiter':100})
        res = basinhopping(risk_budget_objective, initial_weight, niter=50, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs)
```

I have two constraints, one being the sum of weights needs to equal 100% and the other being all weights should be positive.

This solves correctly about 75% of the time, the other times it gets stuck at a local minimum I believe. So a correct result from this would look like:

```
|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|Category|Stock 1    |Stock 2    |Stock 3    |Stock 4    |Stock 5    |Stock 6    |
|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|Weights |0.121465654|0.17829418 |0.091558469|0.105659033|0.156959021|0.346063642|
|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|  
|Risk Con|0.166666667|0.166666667|0.166666667|0.166666667|0.166666667|0.166666667|

Function return val 0.0000000000
```

But occasionally (25% of the times) I will get a result that does not solve the function, like this:

```
|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|Category|Stock 1    |Stock 2    |Stock 3    |Stock 4    |Stock 5    |Stock 6    |
|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|Weights |0.159442825|0.166949713|0.235404372|0.175430619|0.262772472|0.000000000|
|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|  
|Risk Con|0.199661774|0.199803048|0.200448716|0.199943667|0.200142796|0.000000000|

Function return val 33.33371143
```

The times that it is wrong, it seems to completely disregard stock 6. Giving it both a 0 weight and a 0 risk contribution.

Is there any parameter I am not using correctly in the solver? Sorry, this might be a little difficult to solve without the data that I'm using. But just wondering if there is anything obviously wrong with my approach.

I also happen to know there is a solution to the ones scipy doesn't solve correctly because I can do the same thing correctly in an excel spreadsheet with the GRG-nonlinear constraint solver.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Basinhopping is a stochastic global optimizer.  There is no guarantee that it will find the global optimum within the specified number of iterations.

It sounds like from your description that you have a way of checking whether a solution is the global optimum.  In that case you can use the callback parameter to optimize your search

> callback : callable, callback(x, f, accept), optional
>
> A callback function which will be called for all minima found. x and f are the coordinates and function value of the trial minimum, and accept is whether or not that minimum was accepted. This can be used, for example, to save the lowest N minima found. Also, callback can be used to specify a user defined stop criterion by optionally returning True to stop the basinhopping routine.

```
def my_callback(x, f, accept):
    return minimum_is_global_minimum(x)
```

Then you can set niter to some large number and it will stop as soon as it finds the gobal minimum.